# Loading uitableview

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, uitableview, xamarin

I have a uitableview with a button to clear the line.
But after I delete the database record uitableview I want to reload, but I get an error (System.NullReferenceException).
I think this happens because the class inherits (UITableViewSource) and not (UIViewController).
How to solve this?

Below is the class code responsible for loading the uitableview.

Thank you very much

```
public class FonteTabelaExercicios : UITableViewSource
{
    private ExercicioBanco banco = new ExercicioBanco ();
    private List<Exercicio> exercicosBanco;
    private string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";
    UIButton btn;
    private NavController nav = new NavController ();

    public FonteTabelaExercicios (List<Exercicio> banco)
    {
        exercicosBanco = banco;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        if (exercicosBanco != null) {
            return exercicosBanco.Count;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier); 
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);

        cell.TextLabel.Text = exercicosBanco [indexPath.Row].Nome + " - " + exercicosBanco [indexPath.Row].Quantidade;

        btn                 = new UIButton (new CGRect (0, 0, 70, 30));
        btn.SetTitle("Apagar", UIControlState.Normal);
        btn.SetTitleColor (UIColor.White,UIControlState.Normal);
        btn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        cell.AccessoryView  = btn;

        btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {

            int result = 0;

            UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView(
                "Confirmação", 
                "Deseja apagar este dado?", 
                null, 
                NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("Cancelar", "Cancel"),
                NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("OK", "OK")
            );

            alert.Show ();
            alert.Clicked += (object sender2, UIButtonEventArgs es) => { 
                if (es.ButtonIndex == 0 ) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Não");
                }
                else
                {
                    result = banco.ExecutaDelete(exercicosBanco [indexPath.Row]);
                    if (result > 0) {
                        //Loads listaRecorsViewController with uitableview
                        listaRecorsViewController record = (listaRecorsViewController)nav.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("listaRecords");
                        nav.PushViewController(record, false);
                    }
                }
            };
        };

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: Do you want to reload this Uitableview or Insert a new ViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to just reload the `Uitableview` after deleting the row (as explained in the question) you need not instantiate a new ViewController and add it to NavigationController again. There is a `ReloadData` method in `UitableviewSource` class which will reload the whole UITableView data.

You may just edit the Clicked event handler as below

```
alert.Clicked += (object sender2, UIButtonEventArgs es) => { if (es.ButtonIndex == 0 ) { Console.WriteLine("Não"); } 
else { result = banco.ExecutaDelete(exercicosBanco [indexPath.Row]); 
if (result > 0) { 
exercicosBanco.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
ReloadData() ;
} } };
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your source, pass in a reference to the TableViewController:

```
private TableCiewController parent;
public FonteTabelaExercicios (TableViewController parent, List<Exercicio> banco)
{
    exercicosBanco = banco;
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

then, when you need to perform a navigation operation

```
parent.NavigationController.PushViewController(record,false);
```